# How many photos do I need to take to make a panorama?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

How many photos do I need to cover a full circle around the tripod, and all the sky as well?

I've calculated my [angle of view (AOV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view) from their spec sheet, with my [Sony RX10 IV](https://www.sony.com/electronics/cyber-shot-compact-cameras/dsc-rx10m4/specifications) Camera as

$\alpha_{horizon} = 3.4388°$

$\alpha_{vertical} = 2.3150°$

$\alpha_{diagonal} = 4.1446°$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try https://astronomy.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Nosrati: It's not really an astronomy question...

Comment: The entire sky down from the zenith to the horizon covers a solid angle of about $20626$ square degrees.  Each of your photos covers about $8$ square degrees.  Let's add a margin of about $15$ to $20$ percent to allow for necessary overlap, and you probably need about $24000/8 = 3000$ photos.  That's a ballpark figure, and doesn't tell you exactly how to arrange them, although starting each "row" at the same point and having some minimal overlap should be OK.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you attach a large lens to this camera (possibly shooting afocally?), most of your shots will show blank sky.  If you do this during the day, that's not necessarily a problem, although shooting around the Sun might be interesting.  If you're shooting at night, you should be aware that the night sky moves noticeably over the course of just a few minutes.

Comment: @BrianTung I want to basically build a motorized tripod to make "gigapixel" type photos. Any idea on the formula to calculate these kind of things, so I can rework the math a bit for other things like figuring out what motors to use and the gearing?

Comment: How deep are you looking to get, stellar magnitude wise?